# How to post Faker collection in Laravel testing?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a test case where the user will be allowed to create/post multiple items at once. Please take a look at my test:

```php
/**
 * Test multiple item creation.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testMultipleCreation()
{
    $token = Test::generateToken();
    $user = Test::getAuthenticatedUser();
    $stall = factory(Stall::class)->make()->toArray();
    $item = factory(Item::class, 5)->make()->toArray();
    dump($item);

    $user->addStall($stall);
    $response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);
    $response = $response->json('POST', route('items.store', $item));
    $response->assertStatus(200);

    // $this->assertDatabaseHas('items', $item);
}
```

and here is the controller:

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreItem  $request
 * @return \App\Helpers\ResponseMessage
 */
public function store(StoreItem $request)
{
    if (is_array($request)) {
        $this->createMultiple($request);
    }

    $item = auth()->user()->addItem(
        $request->validated()
    );

    return ResponseMessage::created('item', $item);
}

/**
 * Create multiple items.
 *
 * @param array $items
 * @return void
 */
protected function createMultiple($items)
{
    $itemCollection = [];

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemCollection[] = auth()->user()->addItem(
            $item->validated()
        );
    }

    return ResponseMessage::created('items', $itemCollection);
}
```

It works fine if I post it as `$item = factory(Item::class)->make()->toArray();`, but if I make it more than 1 factory item, it fails and throws this error:

> 1) Tests\Unit\ItemTest::testMultipleCreation
>   ErrorException: Array to string conversion
>
> ERRORS!
>   Tests: 9, Assertions: 20, Errors: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is likely here

```
$response = $response->json('POST', route('items.store', $item));
```

Since $item is an Array, it doesn't know how to convert it. 
Probably you meant

```
$response = $response->json('POST', route('items.store'), $item);
```

Comment: I tried that sir, then I got 422 error. the array does not get validated eventhough there is keys matches with the form request.

Comment: That's another issue. Anyway, without having the relevant code about validation I can't help more.

Comment: it's okay sir, i decided to process the request in the front end and remove this feature from the backend. thank you very much for your help